# Local in-memory off heap JVM key-value store

Tags: open-source, library, java

I am looking for a JVM library implementing ConcurrentHashMap to store large map in local memory. Expected to have 20,000,000 items in this map with overall size of 2-3 Gb. No need to distribute data set across hosts.

Load mostly reads with a few writes. Infrequient writes are snapshot updates when whole map content should be replaced with new data.

Would prefer a library with a minimum of dependencies to simplify integration. Would be nice to re-package the library with jarjar for re-distirbution inside my own package.

So far I encountered
* ChronicleMap
* Apache Ignite
* Hazelcast

Could you please recommend which one of those fit my use case better?

Answer (score 1):

**Hazelcast**

For your problem I recommend hazelcast.

***ReplicatedMap***

- Made for extensive read operations.
- Allow you to write custom serialization and deserialization classes which decrease CPU cost while reading and writing.

***Sql-Support***

- Allow you to run SQL query on top of your map.
- Allow you to make indexes on map variables which makes custom retrieval so fast.

***Build***

- Only a single jar is enough to make hazelcast environment.

Answer (score 0):

[MapDb](https://jankotek.gitbooks.io/mapdb/content/quick-start/) appears to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Welcome Igor! Please add to your answer why MapDb appears to be what the OP is looking for.  Thanks!